# Decrypting an HTTP Header with aes_gcm_dec in HA Proxy

Tags: encryption, haproxy

I'm trying to use the HA Proxy [aes_gcm_dec](https://www.haproxy.com/documentation/hapee/latest/onepage/#7.3.1-aes_gcm_dec) converter, but the documentation is sparse to say the least, and I can't find any examples of its use in the community.

I have a client that is sending up a AES GCM 128 encrypted message in an HTTP header, like this:

```
curl -H "X-Routing-Key: e4+DM/EkJQl4jAAOxNtDZb4dd5Q=" localhost:8000
```

I'm using HA Proxy to decrypt that header and forward it to the backend server in decrypted form. Here's my frontend config for that:

```
http-request set-header X-Routing-Key %[req.hdr(X-Routing-Key),b64dec,aes_gcm_dec(128,4+6ONmgZoNex0arqdTr7bA==,Zm9vb2Zvb29mb29wZm9vbw==,4QMQhILaVLC9oxyB8hGoZA==)]
```

The aead tag is hardcoded on the server for now, based on a [simple python script](https://gist.github.com/LeeHampton/197b8a5ab485efbfd0c6ee83cd6dcdde) I wrote for generating the encrypted secret. In the future it will probably be passed up by the client -- same with the nonce. Also, note the `b64dec` converter before the aes_gcm_dec converter. I'm not sure whether or not it's needed. I've tried it both ways and neither works in the current setup.

When I try to do this, HA Proxy silently fails. The header is set to an empty string when it reaches the backend. Even with debug verbosity, HA Proxy doesn't log anything, but clearly something is wrong. Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong here?

Comment: Have you tried to not use `b64dec` because it will be done in the function http://git.haproxy.org/?p=haproxy-2.1.git;a=blob;f=src/ssl_sock.c;hb=36e14bd3189a239a146994e924c0b2fd5f7b6b46#l10702 . you can also catch the value before and after with `http-request capture req.hdr(X-Routing-Key)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have provided this answer on the HAProxy community Slack chat but in case someone finds this on Google you would do something as follows in HAProxy

```
http-request set-var(txn.enc) req.hdr(X-Routing-Key),url_dec,b64dec,bytes(32)
http-request set-var(txn.nonce) req.hdr(X-Routing-Key),url_dec,b64dec,bytes(0,16),base64
http-request set-var(txn.aead_tag) req.hdr(X-Routing-Key),url_dec,b64dec,bytes(16,16),base64
http-request set-header X-Routing-Key %[var(txn.enc),aes_gcm_dec(128,txn.nonce,5AbcQVztUg4LYr406puUkw==,txn.aead_tag)]
```

Make sure your AES output contains the ciphered text, nonce, and aead tag. In the referenced Python it would be something like this:

```
print("X-Routing-Key: %s" % (base64.b64encode(b"".join([aesCipher.nonce, authTag, ciphertext]))).decode('utf-8'))
```

Comment: This works perfectly. However, just as a heads up to future readers: it only works on HA Proxy versions 2.1.5 and higher. I'm not sure what the underlying issue in earlier versions is that causes it to not properly decrypt the message and fail silently.